# MEMS Microphone noise floor power level & audio noise spikes measurement

Tags: noise, measurement, microphone, mems-microphone

I have a circuit with a MEMS microphone and would like to be able to measure the audio noise spike contents and check the noise floor power level in the audio circuit.

My intention is to connect the oscilloscope to the MEMS microphone but before that I would like to know the procedure to analyse the signal shown in the oscilloscope. This is, do measurements need to be done in specific ambient control? Is it necessary to use a specific audio signal for the MEMS microphone to receive and transduce?

On the other hand, maybe using audio fft analysis tools could help. Is there a free one that can be use for this purpose?

Comment: Have you compared the scope noise floor specs with the expected voltage levels of the mic noise?

Comment: So basically I should measure the MEM mic output noise in the oscilloscope and compare it to the datasheet  specs?

Comment: What exactly are your trying to measure? A microphone, *by definition*, will convert the ambient acoustical noise into electrical noise. Determining the amount of noise contributed by the microphone itself is not a trivial exercise.

Comment: Yes, I understand, that´s why I am asking...I would like to measure the idle noise in the ciurcuit right after the MEM microphone. The circuit has a filter after the microphone so I would also like to measure it after the filter and compare both values. I don´t know if this is possible (w/o an anechoic chamber) nor how to do it

Comment: In that case, you want to disconnect the microphone and replace it with a resistor that represents its source impedance.

Comment: Sorry, I´m not explaining quite well...what I need is to check the microphone performance so what I would like is to  to check noise floor pwr level and audio noise spike contents in order to evaluate possible issues in the audio track line

Comment: I will edit the question. sorry for my question and explanation, it´s not clear...

Comment: Must this MEMS sensor perform well, with air_conditioning rumble providing the background acoustic energy floor?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be used in a room with air conditioning...nonetheless maybe it is necessary to use an anechoic chamber to measure these parameters correctly.